# I don't see much info from nvidia-smi/nvtop in Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, graphics

Is this issue because of lack of good driver? I'm mining monero with this GPU (rx/0 algorithm) and I don't see any processes, but this may be due to "CPU thread - GPU" connection. I don't see too deep here.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.103.01   Driver Version: 470.103.01   CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:04:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
| N/A   56C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    240MiB /  1997MiB |     N/A      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

`nvtop` doesn't return much more also:

```
 Device 0 [NVIDIA GeForce GT 710] PCIe GEN N/A RX: N/A TX: N/A
 GPU N/A MHz MEM N/A MHz TEMP  51°C FAN N/A% POW N/A W
 GPU[                              N/A] MEM[|||||                   0.3G/2.1G]
```

And not any processes.

The mining self upon the graphics card increased h/s value and from the log I may say it is working well:

```
 * CUDA         10.1/11.4/6.17.0
 * NVML         11.470.103.01/470.103.01 press e for health report
 * CUDA GPU     #0 04:00.0 NVIDIA GeForce GT 710 954/2505 MHz smx:1 arch:35 mem:1827/1997 MB
[2022-05-14 06:53:28.128]  net      use pool pool.minexmr.com:443 TLSv1.3 94.130.165.85
[2022-05-14 06:53:28.128]  net      fingerprint (SHA-256): "f8cb85d6dc856748d376b48e6b87f90900b3f683fe505ef59de570296761d14b"
[2022-05-14 06:53:28.128]  net      new job from pool.minexmr.com:443 diff 250012 algo rx/0 height 2623025 (11 tx)
[2022-05-14 06:53:28.128]  cpu      use argon2 implementation SSSE3
[2022-05-14 06:53:28.129]  msr      register values for "intel" preset have been set successfully (1 ms)
[2022-05-14 06:53:28.130]  randomx  init datasets algo rx/0 (24 threads) seed 350ff2e03e695aab...
[2022-05-14 06:53:29.293]  randomx  #0 allocated 3072 MB huge pages 100% (1163 ms)
[2022-05-14 06:53:29.293]  randomx  #1 allocated 3072 MB huge pages 100% (1163 ms)
[2022-05-14 06:53:29.293]  randomx  -- allocated 6144 MB huge pages 100% 6/6 (1163 ms)
[2022-05-14 06:53:33.806]  randomx  #1 dataset ready (4513 ms)
[2022-05-14 06:53:34.765]  randomx  #0 dataset ready (959 ms)
[2022-05-14 06:53:34.765]  cpu      use profile  rx  (12 threads) scratchpad 2048 KB
[2022-05-14 06:53:34.767]  nvidia   use profile  rx  (1 thread) scratchpad 2048 KB
|  # | GPU |  BUS ID | INTENSITY | THREADS | BLOCKS | BF |  BS | MEMORY | NAME
|  0 |   0 | 04:00.0 |        64 |      32 |      2 |  0 |   0 |    128 | NVIDIA GeForce GT 710
[2022-05-14 06:53:34.790]  cpu      READY threads 12/12 (12) huge pages 100% 12/12 memory 24576 KB (25 ms)
[2022-05-14 06:53:35.834]  nvidia   READY threads 1/1 (1067 ms)
```